# How can I revert to an older migration in EF Core? (FK key constraint)

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-core-migrations

I am having problems reverting the database model to an earlier migration in EF core. (Version 2.1.14)

I am attempting to update the database model to a previous Migration before I deleted the "WorkingHour" table because I have re-deployed an older version of my build. In other words, I expect the Working hours table to be created upon rollback because that's in the definiton of the "Down" method in the Migration that dropped the table.

I use the command
`update-database [migration-prior-to-deleting-workinghours-tale]` in an attempt to revert to a previous state of the database.

I get an SqlException

> Column Users.UserId is not the same length or scale as referencing
> column "WorkingHours.AdminUserId" in foregin key
> "FK_WorkingHours_Users_AdminUserId" Columns participating in a foreign
> key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.

Which I find strange because that state of the database has been valid in the past. And I would therefore not expect to make any changes to my code in order to roll back to an older (working) build.

I have a model `User` which has a collection of model `WorkingHours` like this:

```cs
public class User 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] //Manually assigned
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    public ICollection<WorkingHour> WorkingHours {get;set;}
}
```

The `WorkingHour` model:

```cs
public class WorkingHour
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public User Admin {get;set;}
}
```

I have applied a migration that did this:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropTable(name: "WorkingHours");
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "WorkingHours",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                AdminUserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_WorkingHours", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_WorkingHours_Users_AdminUserId",
                    column: x => x.AdminUserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "UserId",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_WorkingHours_AdminUserId",
            table: "WorkingHours",
            column: "AdminUserId");
}
```

It is when I revert this migration and attempting to re-create the table `WorkingHours` I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Column 'Users.UserId'
> is not the same length or scale as referencing column
> 'WorkingHours.AdminUserId' in foreign key
> 'FK_WorkingHours_Users_AdminUserId'. Columns participating in a
> foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and
> scale.

Any ideas of what I have done wrong?

Comment: how are you reverting?

Comment: @viveknuna I reverted using the command "update-database [Migration-name]"

Comment: Is there any migration you have added and after that you have not run the `update-database` command? and then you are trying to run the above command?

Comment: @viveknuma To be sure, I ran the"update-database" command before I reverted, but I got the same error.

Comment: then it means, there is some issue with the entities you have defined

Comment: it because the columns are getting created with different length. please check and correct. or define MaxLength to the required value.

Comment: @viveknuna Sorry about not being clear. I meant to say that `update-database` works fine, but it is reverting with the command `update-database [Migration prior to removing working hour]` that fails, even if I had run `update-database` first.

Comment: set the MaxLength for `AdminUserId` and `UserId`

Comment: @viveknuna I'm not sure how I would do that, considering that WorkingHour.cs is not to be kept. To clarify, I have re-released an older build temporarily. So older code, prior to the deletion of the WorkingHour removal, but the migrations failed. I find it strange to have to update the code in order to roll back my database model.

Comment: @PeterAdams Please consider adding an `Edit` to the post and include complete information. That way, others can get a clearer picture of your scenario from the post without going through the comment section.

Comment: @PeterAdams What is the version of EF Core?

Comment: @atiyar I'm using version 2.1.14

Comment: @PeterAdams Is it possible to update EF to the latest and generate your tables again?

Comment: @atiyar Unfortunately, no. I trying to re-deploy to an earlier release (in Azure DevOps) So the code in unchangeable. Upon the release, the database was not updated, so I'm trying to revert to an old migration directly from the command line in Visuals studio. --- Updating the EF Core version and generating the tables would create incongruencies with the published build and the database model, I'm afraid.

Comment: @PeterAdams Ok. I will add an answer with a workaround. You might try that.